# Accessing files from my local machine in Pycharm

Tags: import, pycharm, environment, interpreter

1. I have downloaded the CCTBX library which includes multiple libraries, modules, and methods which I need to access. How do I show Pycharm the location of the CCTBX project so I can access the methods in it.

2.[This is the library on my local machine that I am trying to access.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD6He.png) [I am unable to access the methods, or import the python classes in pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRA9z.png)